# Remove square brackets from cells using pandas

Tags: regex, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe with data as below

```
id, name, date
[101],[test_name],[2019-06-13T13:45:00.000Z]
[103],[test_name3],[2019-06-14T13:45:00.000Z, 2019-06-14T17:45:00.000Z]
[104],[],[]
```

I am trying to convert it to a format as below with no square brackets

Expected output:

```
id, name, date
101,test_name,2019-06-13T13:45:00.000Z
103,test_name3,2019-06-14T13:45:00.000Z, 2019-06-14T17:45:00.000Z
104,,
```

I tried using regex as below but it gave me an error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

```
re.search(r"\[([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\]", df['id'])
```

Comment: @ALollz, its a data set that was shared to me from an external source.

Answer (score 0):

Figured I am able to extract the data using the below:

```
df['id'].str.get(0)
```

Comment: Use `df2 = df.applymap(', '.join)` instead if every column is a list.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the data frame to access each string then use:

```
newstring = oldstring[1:len(oldstring)-1]
```

to replace the cell in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through columns:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].str[1:-1]
```

Or use `apply` if your duplication of your data is not a problem:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str[1:-1])
```

Output:

```
    id        name                                               date
0  101   test_name                           2019-06-13T13:45:00.000Z
1  103  test_name3  2019-06-14T13:45:00.000Z, 2019-06-14T17:45:00....
2  104
```

Or if you want to use regex, you need `str` accessor, and `extract`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.extract('\[([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\]'))
```